# WPF real-time rendering

Tags: wpf, rendering, 2d, real-time

I'm designing a game and thinking about using WPF for making a simple prototype of the basic gameplay.

Is it possible to render basic 2d-graphics in WPF in real-time? By basic graphics I mean simple shapes such as lines, circles, etc. By "real-time" I mean things are rendered based on parameters such as velocity, acceleration, etc. that changes depending on player input - which I assume means I can't use storyboards for the animations.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the previous question [High Performance Graphics using the WPF Visual Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713864/high-performance-graphics-using-the-wpf-visual-layer/8714107#8714107) for a good related discussion. While WPF provides a great framework for rich vector graphics, it lacks somewhat for real-time 2D performance.

There are workarounds, for instance, depending on your scene complexity you may get away with using [DrawingVisuals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) or virtualized Shape classes (WPF Vector graphics) to draw your sprites. Going a little lower level, you could cache sprites using the [BitmapCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapcache%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) mode available in .NET4.0, or pre-prendering them to Bitmaps and using various [optimization patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317460/bitmap-performance-optimization-patterns/9467543#9467543) to improve throughput.

Going lower level still, you can mix Vector/Raster graphics using the fantantastic [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) project, or Vector/GPU graphics using the [D3DImage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28526/Introduction-to-D3DImage).

Regarding how to update your scene, you'll need to write a primitive game engine where on the [CompositionTarget.Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx) event (fired on redraw of the screen) you get the updated parameters and compute positions/orientations of your sprites. Something that might help with this is this great [codeplex project](http://physicshelper.codeplex.com/) which integrates WPF/Silverlight and Farseer physics.