# WPF - Interactive real-time rendering(C#)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, real-time, interactive

I am currently working on a project where i want to display data of a game and my own graphs on a rebuilt minimap.

The data is given as ticks of the game with the entitydata changed in that tick. At first i want to draw the map and then all entities existing at the first tick. Then for every tick i want to update positions and draw lines between entities

My WPF User Interface is set up with the MVVM Pattern.

Now i am struggling with the creation of and techniques for the minimap.

What i want the minimap to support/create:

1. Interactivity

   - Click on entities on the field to display more information about them.
   - Zoom the map
   - Follow entities(with a zoomed in game field)
   - Toogle different visuals (disable one team, highlight sth etc)
   - ...(and other interactions like the above)
2. Performance

   - Graphics should look as smooth as possible(Map,Images, anti-aliasing, no stuttering)
   - High framerate (at least 30FPS)
   - At best it should be a solution with most of the above features built in(see 1.)
3. Exporting screenshots and a video of the whole game(with my own graphs and stuff)

What i already considered(from this post [WPF real-time rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571999/wpf-real-time-rendering))

- Data binding and canvas

Problem: Slow and not performant..at least as I implemented it)
- WriteableBitmap(Problem: No funcitionalities built in(see 1.)

- DrawingVisuals

Problem: How to realize as MVVM? Is it efficient?

- WriteableBitMap

Problem: I have to build the functionality of 1.) on my own. But looks like it is efficient

Before i start implementing a lot of my wanted features myself i wanted to ask if there is anything fitting my needs or if any of the above technologies is not suited.

I hope that my question is clear enough.

Feel free to let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: [This Library](https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx/) will give you all the drawing functions you are used to for drawing on a `WritableBitmap`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: Does it also support hit testing? It may become more complicated than imagined when working with zoom and translation.

Comment: It is just a drawing library, you would still need to hit-test on your own. I would recommend creating a `UserControl`, drawing with `WritableBitmapEx` and doing the hit-testing directly in the code-behind of the `UserControl`.  You can use `DrawingVisual` to do the hit-test.  MVVM really breaks down for something like this, as hit-testing is really part of the direct UI layer, rather than the view-model layer.

Comment: Zoom and Translation should be fairly easy to handle if you create a class that can take screen-space cords, and converts them to map-space coords.  It could probably be done with  a fairly simple matrix calculation.  You might even be able to throw rotation in to the mix too.

Comment: thanks for the input so far.

Answer (score 0):

DataBinding is nice for connecting view models to input controls, but not for updating the state of graphic objects in real-time.

I would go with [DrawingVisual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/using-drawingvisual-objects) because it is relative lightweight and supports [hit testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms608753(v=vs.110).aspx). Even if you don't have MVVM support, it is easy to update the visuals "manually".